# Conflict between LEAF and MAP after upgrading spring-cloud-config-server

Tags: spring, cloud, spring-cloud-config

I'm  using spring-cloud-config-server 1.2.2..RELEASE.

I need to update it to a newer version (e.g. 1.4.4..RELEASE, but the issue happens in the latest version as well)). When I tried to update the version and performed a call to the YAML endpoint of the config server (with test profile requested), I got an error (`ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map`) on some of my properties.

These properties are defined in application.yaml as a LEAF:

```
logging.level.com.company: DEBUG
```

But are defined as MAP on my application specific profile YAML (application-test.yaml):

```
logging.level.com.company.salesforce.editor.service: DEBUG
```

Previously, I got in the response YAML something like:

```
logging:
    level:
        com:
            company: DEBUG
            company.salesforce.editor.service: DEBUG
```

- I debugged the spring-cloud-config-server code I found out there was a major change (from 1.2.x to 1.3.x) in `EnvironmentController.java\convertToMap(Environment input, boolean resolvePlaceholders)()` that probably caused it.
- I found this GitHub issue on a similar issue:
  [ClassCastException with specific logging settings](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/725)
  But it wasn't helpful to me.

How can I use the new version, but get the same response as in the old version? If not possible, what is another course of action I can take?

**EDIT**

I've created a demo project to illustrate the problem - Clone it from here:

[spring-cloud-config-server-demo](https://github.com/eyalrin/spring-cloud-config-server-demo)

(It uses the following git backend for configurations: [spring-cloud-config-server-configurations](https://github.com/eyalrin/spring-cloud-config-server-configurations))

Once the demo server is up and running, query it like so:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/master/application-test.yaml
```

and you will get this error:

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map
```

Comment: A question starting with "Does anyone know" is only answerable by "yes" or "no". Neither of these answers is going to be very helpful. And that is because that is not a question about programming (as appropriate for this site). Try to ask questions, for which the answer directly helps you, "How do I ...?", "How can I ... ?", that makes it much more clear what you really want to know.

Comment: OK, thanks for the correction.

Comment: We are no longer supporting 1.2.x or 1.3.x.  You should be using 1.4.x or 2.0.x releases.

Comment: The issue happens in the latest versions as well - Edited the question

Comment: Please provide a sample to reproduce the issue

Comment: @RyanBaxter  demo project was added to the post

Comment: Your configuration is invalid.  You have `logging.level.com.company: DEBUG` and also `logging.level.com.company.salesforce.editor.service: DEBUG`.  `logging.level.com.company` is both equal to a String and a Map.

Comment: This is exactly the issue I'm querting about - In spring cloud config version 1.2.2 it worked - It automaticly created a new key for the latter when called the YAML endpoint (see the response I used to get in my post). Now, the behaviour has changed and it fails on it. I understand that the configuration should have been originaly defined a different way, but since it worked before, and I have a lot of configuration files using this "bad" way of defining keys, I cannot upgrade to a newer version since there are breaking changes in newer version.. unless there's a workaroind you know about?

Comment: There is no workaround that I know about besides fixing your configuration.  It may have worked in prior versions but that was the bug we were fixing.